# How to rewrite SQL Union of two tables with Join in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 classes as below:

```
public class A
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Age {get; set;}
    public bool IsEmployed {get; set;}
    public int RoleId {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Age {get; set;}
    public int RoleId {get; set;}
}

public class Roles
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string RoleName {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Suppose these classes have their own tables on the DBMS.

I currently have an SQL query which I would like to rewrite in LINQ (as elegantly as possible)

```
SELECT A.Name, A.Age, Roles.RoleName, A.IsEmployed 
FROM A 
JOIN Roles ON A.RoleId = Roles.Id
WHERE Roles.RoleName = 'ADMIN'

UNION

SELECT B.Name, B.Age, Roles.RoleName, '-' as IsEmployed 
FROM B 
JOIN Roles ON B.RoleId = Roles.Id
WHERE Roles.RoleName = 'ADMIN'
```

Currently I have managed to rewrite it as:

```
var filteredClassA = from c in allClassAs
    join role in allRoles on role.Id equals c.RoleId
    where role.RoleName == "ADMIN"
    SELECT new {c.Name, c.Age, role.RoleName, c.IsEmployed};

var filteredClassB = from c in allClassBs
    join role in allRoles on role.Id equals c.RoleId
    where role.RoleName == "ADMIN"
    SELECT new {c.Name, c.Age, role.RoleName, IsEmployed = "-"};
```

Then I can concat or union the results into one variable like so:

```
var result = filteredClassA.Union(filteredClassB);
```

I don't like this solution, is there a better way to do all the above in a single LINQ query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option, in only one query:

```
var result = allClassAs.Join(allRoles, c => c.Id, role => role.Id, (c, role) => new {c.Name, c.Age, role.RoleName, c.IsEmployed})
                        .Where(r => r.RoleName == "ADMIN")
                        .Union(allClassBs.Join(allRoles, c => c.Id, role => role.Id, (c, role) => new {c.Name, c.Age, role.RoleName, IsEmployed = "-"})
                        .Where(r => r.RoleName == "ADMIN"));
```

Comment: Beat me to it! This is exactly what you would do. Personally I think the original way of doing it is easier to understand.

Comment: I think the first way is easier, but he finds way to do all the above in a single LINQ query

Answer (score 1):

```
(from a in context.A
where a.Roles.Any(r=>r.RoleName == "ADMIN")
select new {Name = a.Name, Age = a.Age, Role = "ADMIN", Employed = a.IsEmployed})
.Union(
from b in context.B
where b.Roles.Any(r=>r.RoleName == "ADMIN")
select new {Name = b.Name, Age = b.Age, Role = "ADMIN".RoleName, Employed = "-"}
)
```